# window.location.href not redirecting to external url inside await method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function like below

```
const redirect = async ()  => {
    await aFunc().then(async () => {
        await bFunc().then((externalUrl) => {
            window.location.href = externalUrl;
        });
    });
}
```

from react component calling this function like below

`<Button onClick={ async() => { await redirect(); }}></Button>`

When I debugged this code, I noticed that when it's executing the line "window.location.href", it's not redirecting to external url instead just reloading the page it self

Comment: Have you checked the value of `externalUrl` before redirecting?

Comment: @Teemu yes I am getting value there

Comment: This sounds like a pending form submission, just not sure how it can be awaited, normally submission aborts async actions.

Comment: share more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `(externalUrl) = { ... }` needs to be changed into arrow notation like,

```
   await bFunc().then((externalUrl) => {
        window.location.href = externalUrl;
    });
```

Apart from that I have included both `aFunc` and `bFunc` with a promise resolved inside it with a `setTimeout`.

So here redirect function makes the redirection of `window.location.href` to the `externalUrl` once resolved.

**Working Snippet:**

```js
const App = () => {

  const aFunc = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("resolved");
      }, 500);
    });
  }

  const bFunc = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("https://stackoverflow.com");
      }, 500);
    });
  }

  const redirect = async () => {
    await aFunc().then(async () => {
      await bFunc().then((externalUrl) => {
        if(externalUrl) {
         window.location.href = externalUrl;
        }
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={async () => {
          await redirect();
        }}
      >
        Click Here
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
```

**Codesandbox:**

[image: Edit exciting-haibt-f4r8kn]

Comment: adding setTimeOut resolved the issue